# get text of the current node only

Tags: enzyme

I'm using airbnb's enzyme library for react testing and I want to retrieve the text of the current node only, excluding any text from any child nodes.

```
  const component = <div>hello<span>there</span></div>
```

If I do:

```
  shallow(component).find('div').text()  //hellothere
```

If I do:

```
  shallow(component).find('span').text()  //there
```

How do I get just `hello` ?

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`.childAt()`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/childAt.html)

```
shallow(component).find('div').childAt(0) // hello
```

`.childAt()` will return the child at the index specified

Comment: `shallow(component).find('div').childAt(0).text()`. This worked for me actually. But my code was a bit different.

Comment: This does the exact opposite for me. Running `.childAt(0)` on the following `<div>ops@example.com<SomeOtherReactElement>abc</SomeOtherReactElement></div>` gives me `abc`. While `.childAt(1)` gives me an element not found error.